# ERROR - {time} --> Severity: Warning --> array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given instagram_helper.php 169

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

in my logs of codeigniter script i seen this error :

> ERROR - 2018-02-12 03:54:11 --> Severity: Warning --> array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given /home/webhouse/public_html/app/helpers/instagram_helper.php 169

line 169 of instagram_helper.php :

```
return array_values($feeds);
```

and this is instagram_helper.php php codes :

```
function instacurl(){
    if(FX == 1){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}

function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

function removeFeedVideo($result){
    if(!empty($result)){
        foreach ($result as $key => $row) {
            if($row->media_type != 1){
                unset($result[$key]);
                continue;
            }
        }
        return array_values($result);
    }
}

function removeFeedPrivate($result){
    if(!empty($result)){
        foreach ($result as $key => $row) {
            if(isset($row->user) && $row->user->is_private == 1){
                unset($result[$key]);
                continue;
            }
        }
        return array_values($result);
    }
}

function removePrivateUser($result){
    if(!empty($result)){
        foreach ($result as $key => $row) {
            if($row->is_private == 1){
                unset($result[$key]);
                continue;
            }
        }

        return array_values($result);
    }
}

function removePrivateUserComments($result){
    if(!empty($result)){
        foreach ($result as $key => $row) {
            if($row->user->is_private == 1){
                unset($result[$key]);
                continue;
            }
        }
        return array_values($result);
    }
}

function removeFeedBlackLists($feeds,$bl_tags,$bl_usernames,$bl_keywords){
    // pr(count($feeds),0);
    $feeds=json_encode($feeds);
    $feeds=json_decode($feeds);
    // pr($feeds,1);
    foreach ($feeds as $key => $row) {
        $check_tags=false;
        $check_usernames=false;
        $check_keywords=false;
        if(!empty($row->preview_comments)&&is_array($row->preview_comments)) {
            if(!empty($row->preview_comments[0])){
                $preview_comments_1 = $row->preview_comments[0];
                $preview_comments_1 = strtolower($preview_comments_1->text);
                if(!empty($row->preview_comments[1])){
                    $preview_comments_2 = $row->preview_comments[1];
                    $preview_comments_2 = strtolower($preview_comments_2->text);
                    $preview_comments = $preview_comments_1.' '.$preview_comments_2;
                }
            }
        }
        $caption_text="";
        if(!empty($row->caption->text)){
            $caption_text = strtolower($row->caption->text);
            // pr($caption_text,0);
        }

        if(isset($preview_comments)){
            $caption_text.=' '.$preview_comments;
            $caption_hashtags=getDataFromString($caption_text,$target="hashtags");
        }
        if (!empty($row->user)) {
            $blist_usernames = $row->user;
            $blist_usernames = strtolower($blist_usernames->username);
        }
        if(!empty($caption_text)){
            $caption_usernames=getDataFromString($caption_text,$target="usernames");
            $caption_usernames[]="@".$blist_usernames;
            $caption_usernames = array_count_values($caption_usernames);
            $caption_usernames = array_keys($caption_usernames);
        }
        if (!empty($bl_tags)&&is_array($bl_tags)&&!empty($caption_hashtags)&&is_array($caption_hashtags)) {
            if ($check_usernames==false&&$check_keywords==false) {
                foreach ($bl_tags as $pattern) {
                    $pattern  = trim($pattern);
                    $pattern  = "#".$pattern;
                    foreach ($caption_hashtags as $val) {
                        if ($pattern==$val) {
                            // echo "<b style='color:blue;'>Khớp bl_tags: $pattern</b><br>";
                            // echo "<i style='color:red;'>text</i>";
                            // pr($caption_text,0);
                            // echo "<i style='color:red;'>comment</i>";
                            // echo "<b style='color:red;'>Ton tai TAGS</b>";
                            $check_tags=true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if ($check_tags) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // usernames
        if(!empty($bl_usernames)&&is_array($bl_usernames)&&!empty($caption_usernames)&&is_array($caption_usernames)){
            if ($check_tags==false&&$check_keywords==false) {
                foreach ($bl_usernames as $pattern) {
                    $pattern  = trim($pattern);
                    $pattern  = "@".$pattern;
                    foreach ($caption_usernames as $val) {
                        if ($pattern==$val) {
                            $check_usernames=true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if ($check_usernames) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // keywords
        if(!empty($bl_keywords)&&is_array($bl_keywords)&&is_string($caption_text)){
            if ($check_tags==false&&$check_usernames==false) {
                $re = '/\b(?:' . join('|', array_map(function($keyword) {return preg_quote($keyword, '/'); }, $bl_keywords)) . ')\b/i';
                if (preg_match_all($re, $caption_text, $matches)>0) {
                    $check_keywords=true;
                }
            }
        }
        if ($check_tags==true||$check_usernames==true||$check_keywords==true) {
            unset($feeds[$key]);
        }
    }
    //pr(count($feeds),0);
    return array_values($feeds);
}
```

any idea ?

Comment: try `return array_values((array) $feeds);`?

Comment: @NikolaGavric your code replaces, thanks you. i'll report feedback, thank U <3